# Making a $1,0,-1$ linear commbination of primes a multiple of $1000$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that with every given 10 primes $p_1,p_ 2,\ldots,p_{10}$,there always exist 10 number which are not simultaneously equal to $0$, get one of three values: $-1$, $0$, $1$ satisfied that:
$\sum\limits_{ i=1}^{10}a_ip_i$ is a multiple of 1000

Comment: Please post one question at a time, or explain the relationship you perceive between the questions.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i have just edited:). To Gerry Myerson: that is symbol familiar in my country, so sorry, edited of course

Answer (score 4):

The pigeonhole principle takes care of this. There are $2^{10}-1=1023$ non-empty sums, so two are congruent modulo $1000$, etc., etc.

Comment: please more specific, if there are two sum congruent modulo 1000, what do you do next? for example, if $p_1$ exists in two sum, how can you contruct a sum satisfies that $a_1=1$

Comment: I'm intentionally leaving some work for you to do. Don't you want the pleasure of solving a problem on your own?

Comment: ok.i proved. thanks.

Comment: Good. Now *you* can post a complete solution here. After a while, you can even accept your own solution.

Answer (score 3):

Following the guide of Gerry Myerson, i think here is solution of this problem. First, we'll built 1,0 linear combination of 10 primes. There are $2^{10}$ combination except for one Zero combination, so we get $2^{10}-1=1023$ non zero combination. Then exists two of them congruents modulo 1000, take their subtraction, we have 1,0,-1 linear combination which is multiple of 1000. This is not so difficult problem, and we can replace 
"prime" hypothesis by "abitrary integer". and the number 1000 can replaced by $1<a<1023$. anyway, make it clear of my mind. thanks to Gerry:)

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the linear combination in this case?

Comment: @A.Schulz, the linear combination (or combinations --- there could be several) will depend, of course, on which $10$ primes are given.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oh I see. I misread the question. I thought the $p_i$s are the first 10 primes.

Comment: @A.Schulz, for the first $10$ primes, you can take $2+3-5$, with all the other coefficients zero, or $3+5+11-19$, or any of a number of other solutions.

Comment: @Schulz:don't let your intention to hypothesis "prime". this solution can apply for any 10 integer^^